# If 4D QED is also not known to exist in a mathematically precise way why is the Clay Institute problem only about YM non-abelian QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, yang-mills

Many mainstream QFT textbooks make some reference to the lack of proof for the existence of in fact any interacting quantum field theory in 4 dimensions (for instance Schwartz's book in page 267). So why not include QED in the [Millennium problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yang%E2%80%93Mills_existence_and_mass_gap#Importance_of_Yang%E2%80%93Mills_theory) about quantum field theory? Is there some physics related reason?

Comment: I don't know what specifically motivated the Clay institute, but the problem as stated includes the existence of a mass gap, which QED doesn't have

Comment: I don't know if this is the reason or not, but QED on its own is not a complete theory at arbitrarily high energies (see these articles about [Landau poles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_pole) and [quantum triviality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_triviality)). On the other hand, QCD should approach a sensible fixed point in the UV under the flow of the [renormalization group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renormalization_group). So, proving the existence and mass gap of Yang-Mills would prove the existence of a non-trivial QFT that was valid to arbitrarily high energies.

Comment: [This](https://www.claymath.org/sites/default/files/yangmills.pdf) is the document in which the Clay Institute explains their choice. (I don't think they explicitly address the OP's question though)

Comment: In QED, the perturbative approach works well. That is, for asymptotically free particles. If you could find a non-perturbative (I can't even imagine what that looks like) approach for bound systems (say, a hydrogen atom) you would indeed have found something! I think because of the fact that the non-perturbative approach is used mainly in QCD (so not in QED) that the CLAY institute has promised a million dollars for solving the problem (which is related to perturbative QCD) they proposed. QED can't solve that problem. If you could show how a bound state emerges in QED, equally impressive!

Comment: [Haag's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haag%27s_theorem), on which there are several questions on this site, is thought to be chipping on the edges of the mainstream theory.  Devising feel-good workarounds is not thought to be urgent or promising.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about the Clay Institute's reasons for choosing specific problems and not others as their Millenium Problems, which are not guaranteed to be about physics as a natural science.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QED as a theory of infra-particles may be constructed, in my opinion. It is not constructed yet because it is not a "mainstream direction" anymore, unfortunately, and it is not funded as a promising direction. Mathematicians at CLAY do not feel its physical necessity, it appears.